# SQL Server Container database cloning support

Tags: sql-server, windows, containers

I'm working with Windows Server Core 1709, using SMB file share support for SQL containers.    Support for small databases works well (allowing time to copy databases), but now I face the need for provisioning environments that include databases of 100's of GB in size.   I've worked in the past with SAN based snapshots, but don't have access to these resources.   Is anyone familiar with SQL Server database cloning that could be employed for this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

Windocks has just released database cloning support for Docker SQL Server containers, all versions and editions SQL 2008 forward.   Take a look at https://www.windocks.com/docker-sql-server-containers

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product, website or blog, **you must disclose your affiliation in the answer**. Otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).